# how to split the csv file in this case

Tags: python

attachment = 'attachment; filename*=utf-8''' + urllib.parse.quote(_filename)

```
    auditlog_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
    auditlog_data_csv = auditlog_data_frame.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf8')
    
    return response
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for something like this

```
with open(filename) as input_file:
    output_file = None
    for index, line in enumerate(input_file):
        if index % 1_000_000 == 0:
            if output_file:
                output_file.close()
            output_file = open(f'output{index}', "w")
        output_file.write(line)
    output_file.close()
```

Comment: Since Python 3.6 you can use __underscores__ in numeric literals (see [PEP515](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep515)): `million = 1_000_000` to improve readability,
There is even a library like [filesplit](https://pypi.org/project/filesplit/): `Split(infile, outdir).bylinecount(1_000_000)`